# Read CSV file which contains '\' string and '\0' enclosures using opencsv?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I use RFC4180Parser to read files contain `'\'`, and `"` before. It worked perfectly.

There is my code, I'm using `RFC4180Parser` and `CsvToBeanBuilder` to read the CSV file.

```
final RFC4180Parser rfc4180Parser = new RFC4180ParserBuilder().build();
final CSVReaderBuilder csvReaderBuilder = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader(inputDpaCsvFilePath))
    .withCSVParser(rfc4180Parser);
final List<MyClass> infos = new CsvToBeanBuilder<MyClass>(csvReaderBuilder.build())
    .withType(MyClass.class)
    .withSeparator(',')
    .build().parse();
```

**Original CSV file:**

```
"A",       "B",        "C",       "D"
"value 1", "value 2",  "value 3", "value 4"
"value\\" 11", "value 22\\"", "value 33", "value 44"
```

But now the file format changes. Some commas have been added to the `Header E` column.

**New CSV file:**

```
"Header A",   "Header B",  "Header C", "Header D", "Header E"
"value1",     "value2",    "value3",   "value4",   "spA, spB, spC"
"value\\"5",  "value6\\"",   "value 7",  "value8",   "spA, spC"
"value\\" 9", "value 10", "value 11", "value 12", "spC"
```

There will thrown Exception as below:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Number of data fields does not match number of headers.
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Number of data fields does not match number of headers.
    at com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.verifyLineLength(HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java:110)
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:313)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:132)
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:85)
    ... 3 more
```

How do I update my code to read this CSV file?

Comment: Don't override the separator?

Comment: The default separator is also char ',', in ICSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR.

Comment: so have you tried with `.withSeparator(',')` removed?

Comment: Is line 3 in original csv and line 3-4 in new csv actual source? I can't parse with those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [RCF4180 specification section 2.4](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt)

> 4. Within the header and each record, there may be one or more
>    fields, separated by commas.  Each line should contain the same
>    number of fields throughout the file.  **Spaces are considered part
>    of a field and should not be ignored**.  The last field in the
>    record must not be followed by a comma.  For example:
>
>    aaa,bbb,ccc

Hence error "Number of data fields does not match number of headers." is thrown because

```
"value1",     "value2",    "value3",   "value4",   "spA, spB, spC"
```

is parsed as 7 fields (please note the leading space and the double quote.):

```
value1
     "value2"
    "value3"
   "value4"
   "spA
 spB
 spC
```

but header only contains 5 fields.

---

Without modifying the csv, we can use [`CSVParser`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVParser.html) instead of [`RFC4180Parser`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/RFC4180Parser.html), and [ignoring leading white space](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVParserBuilder.html#withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace-boolean-). Following program demonstrates how to use `CSVParser` to parse provided csv and how `RFC4180Parser` parses field with leading spaces :

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.opencsv.CSVParser;
import com.opencsv.CSVParserBuilder;
import com.opencsv.CSVReaderBuilder;
import com.opencsv.RFC4180Parser;
import com.opencsv.RFC4180ParserBuilder;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvException;

public class ParseCsvFieldContainsCommaAndLeadingSpaceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CsvException {
        parseWithCSVParser();
        parseWithRFC4180Parser();
    }

    private static void parseWithCSVParser() throws IOException, CsvException {
        final CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true).build();
        final CSVReaderBuilder csvReaderBuilder = new CSVReaderBuilder(
                new StringReader("\"Header A\",   \"Header B\",  \"Header C\", \"Header D\", \"Header E\"\r\n" +
                        "\"value1\",     \"value2\",    \"value3\",   \"value4\",   \"spA, spB, spC\""))
                                .withCSVParser(parser);
        System.out.println("Result from CSVParser");
        List<String[]> lines = csvReaderBuilder.build().readAll();
        for (String[] line : lines) {
            System.out.println(String.join(" | ", line));
        }
    }

    private static void parseWithRFC4180Parser() throws IOException, CsvException {
        final RFC4180Parser rfc4180Parser = new RFC4180ParserBuilder().build();
        final CSVReaderBuilder csvReaderBuilder = new CSVReaderBuilder(
                new StringReader("\"Header A\",   \"Header B\",  \"Header C\", \"Header D\", \"Header E\"\r\n" +
                        "\"value1\",     \"value2\",    \"value3\",   \"value4\",\"spA, spB, spC\""))
                                ////////////////////////////////// Removed space ^ to runnable
                                .withCSVParser(rfc4180Parser);
        System.out.println("Result from RFC4180Parser");
        List<String[]> lines = csvReaderBuilder.build().readAll();
        for (String[] line : lines) {
            System.out.println(String.join(" | ", line));
        }
    }
}
```